# Tango SDK can't set custom exposure or ISO

Tags: java, android, google-project-tango

I am using the latest Tango SDK (Corporales) on the Lenovo Phab2. I would like to use the RGB camera, but set with a custom value for the exposure and ISO from code. I need the depth data and pose estimates too, so have to depend entirely on the Tango SDK. I have set the bool to auto colour mode to false and then set the ISO value, but there is still no change to the image.

The documentations says it should work, but from what I can see, it doesn't work at all. I am using the Java SDK. Just to rule out programming errors, I also tried it on one of the official examples from Google and modified it to set the custom ISO value.